# Different datetimes displayed in view and template in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-database

When I display a datetime object in my template, the displayed result is a date very different from what I have in my database. Printing the datetime in the view for debbuging gives the same result as the dabatase. I'm guessing it gets parsed somewhere between the view and the rendered template which gives a different date but I cannot pinpoint exactly what's going on.

I'm using DateTimeField in the database.

Comment: Can you share relevant code as well?

Comment: I often see it. In template the time is localized( it get use of tzinfo). Python print does not. Use timezone.localtime(your datetime)